# Python - Reading a partial CSV Cell

Tags: python, csv

For a project, I'm looking at splitting up the data contained in a cell of a CSV file - the CSV file is output by another device and cannot altered. The CSV cell in question will have 8 characters, the first 4 will be used to specify an X coordinate, and the last 4 the y coordinate. I would like to be able to read the first 4 characters, save them as a variable and repeat for the last 4. Is this possible with the python CSV reader ?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, I think `int()` should be enough for the job

Comment: the solution you're looking for is `x=int(cell[:4])` and `y=int(cell[4:])` , or `float` if the value isn't always an integer

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

```
import csv
with open('csv_file.csv') as f:
    csv_data = []
    cr = csv.reader(f)
    for row in cr:
        csv_data.append(row)
# say the data you want is in (both zero-indexed) row 3, column 5
x_coord = csv_data[3][5][:4]
y_coord = csv_data[3][5][4:]
```

If all the cells are like this (and need to be split) you can do this while you read the file into csv_data.

```
import csv
with open('csv_file.csv') as f:
    csv_data = []
    cr = csv.reader(f)
    for row in cr:
        x_coords = [c[:4] for c in row]
        y_coords = [c[4:] for c in row]
        csv_data.append(zip(x_coords, y_coord))
```

So if originally cell (0,0) was `'00340633'` representing coordinates: ('0034', '0633'), now it will be `csv_data[0][0]` will be `('0034', '0633')`.  You may want to convert to `int` or `float`.  E.g., `x_coords = [int(c[:4]) for c in row]` depending on the type of data in each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to split a string with fixed 8 characters? Try this code below:

```
test =  'aaaabbbb'
print(test[0:4])
print(test[4:])
```

Or if there is a sign in middle, you could split it as well:

```
test2 =  'aaaa bbbb'
# split by blank, putput is a list
print(test2.split(' '))  
# Result: ['aaaa', 'bbbb']
```